# Converting time interval to Date or number in React

Tags: reactjs, date, intervals

Is anyone aware of a library I can use in React that converts locale aware time interval to either Date interval or a number (e.g., a number of seconds). For instance:

```
"2min" -> 120
"2 minutes" -> 120
"2 Minuten" -> 120 (locale: de)
```

and so on.

Can do it myself of course, but feels like a thing that someone has already done before...

PS. I am using `date-fns` to do the opposite conversion.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following function:

```
 function localSekundenConvert(timeInString){
 const splitTime = timeInString.toLowerCase().split('m');
 const minuten = splitTime[0];
 const sekunden=minuten*60
 const formatSekunden=`${sekunden} sekunden`
 console.log(formatSekunden)
 return formatSekunden;
  }

 localSekundenConvert("33 minuten")
```

Comment: Thanks… what if it is “2분”

Comment: just change the end of second line from 'm' to '분'